# Sitefinity user control

Tags: c#, sitefinity

In Sitefinity - the page controls section I created a new tool and linked it up to the user control. But when I try and add that control to the page I am getting an error?

> Is there a step I am missing?

[image: Error argument was out of range]

UserControl

```
 Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TransparencyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.transparency.TransparencyControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ucTransparency" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<asp:Xml ID="XmlForm" runat="server"></asp:Xml>
```

PageControl
[image: Created the PageControl]

PageControl tool linked to ascx page
[image: PageControl Tools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the path to the user control (ascx) not in the Controller CLR Type field, but in Control CLR Type or Virtual Path field.

So, just cut it from the former field and paste it in the latter field and you should be fine.